# Finding ? operator in AST

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, rascal, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm doing some exercise in Rascal. When I try to determine the Cyclomatic complexity of a Java method getting methods from an AST. I would like to evaluate the ? operator.
As it is not determined by '/if(_, _, *)', I tried to determine it using postfix(*, _); (infix works fine finding || or &&)
Still no success.
Anybody who can unhide this secret to me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Wouldn't this be `\conditional(_,_,_)`? (I'm assuming this, but haven't done much with the M3 AST for Java, it just looks like the right constructor.)

Comment: Thanks, As a beginner in Rascal I just overlooked.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the force; the source for the AST definition is here https://github.com/cwi-swat/rascal/blob/master/src/org/rascalmpl/library/lang/java/m3/AST.rsc, also mentioning the `conditional` constructor Mark pointed out in his comment.

If you use `iprintln` on the AST for a small example, like `iprintln(ast)` or `import util::ValueUI;` and then `text(ast)` for an editor with the formatted AST it's easy to find out what ASTs look like.